# SAT verifier python

Tags: python, sympy, sat

I am using python and Sympy.

I have rules of the following format: `Or(x,And(y,z))`. 
Unfortunately, Sympy `subs` and `xreplace` functions doesn't provide fast enough implementation for verifying if the above rule is satisfied for x=False, y=True and z=True.

How can I efficiently convert this expression to some other library that given x,y,z and a rule I will get True/False whether this assigning satisfies the rules or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in pure python in 2 ways (with `x=True/False, y=True/False, z=True/False`):

```
x or (y and z)
```

or (as `0 == False, 1 == True`):

```
x | (y & z)
```

you could then iterate over all combinations with:

```
from itertools import product

for x, y, z in product((True, False), repeat=3):
    print(x, y, z)
    print(x or (y and z))
    print(x | (y & z))
    print()
```

in  order to convert the sympy function to the python expression you could try the [`lambdify` module](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html):

```
from sympy import lambdify, Or, And, var

x, y, z = var('x y z')
or_and = lambdify((x, y, z), Or(x, And(y, z)))
print(or_and(True, False, False))
```

hope that speeds your problem up as much as you hope...

Comment: These are good suggestion but the question is how to efficiently convert what the expression in Sympy for to the new form you suggested.

Comment: @JackStevens: ok, misunderstood, sorry. added an update. hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks good. I have tried to implement it in my code which resulted in a different problem that I have posted another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045906/typeerror-return-arrays-must-be-of-arraytype-using-lambdify-of-sympy-in-python) for.