# TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType using lambdify of sympy in python

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, sympy

I have the following code:

```
x,y,z,t = var('x,y,z,t')
d = set([t])
rule = And(Or(x,y,z),t)
atoms = tuple(rule.atoms())
params = [True if i in d else False for i in atoms]
lam = lambdify(atoms, rule)
lam(*params)
```

which throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#142>", line 7, in <module>
lam(*params)
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

And I can't understand why, for other rules it works great.

Answer (score 3):

**Update: This bug was fixed in SymPy 1.2, see [its release notes](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Release-Notes-for-1.2#minor-changes). If you are experiencing this bug update your SymPy installation.**

---

This one's pretty tricky, and surprising. Here's the docstring of your lambda named `lam`:

```
<lambda> lambda _Dummy_22, _Dummy_23, _Dummy_24, _Dummy_25
    Created with lambdify. Signature:

    func(z, x, y, t)

    Expression:

    And(Or(x, y, z), t)
```

So far so good. Well, I'd already note that your input arguments are being chosen automatically, and you don't know their order. I'd explicitly set an order such as `lambdify((x,y,z,t),rule)`, but I don't know your actual application (I just thought I'd note this).

Anyway, trying it within sympy obviously works fine:

```
>>> And(Or(False,False,False),True)
False
```

On my system within IPython, this is the full error I get:

```
----> 1 lam(*params)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <lambda>(_Dummy_34, _Dummy_35, _Dummy_36, _Dummy_37)

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Note the numpy path in the error. Since I have numpy installed, `lambdify` tries to map the symbolic expression to numpy functions. Since you only have `And` and `Or` in your expression, I can only assume these are `numpy.logical_and` and `numpy.logical_or`, respectively. But here's the deal (going back to the vanilla REPL for simplicity):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.logical_or(False,False,False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Oops, there's your problem: numpy's logical operators are binary! The same goes for `operator.and_`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.and_(False,False,False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: op_and_ expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

The standard logical operators which `lambdify` uses to convert your symbolic expression to numerical don't accept more than two input arguments. The reason for the cryptic error message in the numpy case is that the third input argument of the binary ufunc `logical_or` is interpreted as an output array instead of a third operand, but in this sympy context this is entirely unexpected.

My suggestion is to use `all/any` or `numpy.all/numpy.any` for your specific example, passed as the `modules` keyword argument of `lambdify`:

```
>>> lam = lambdify(atoms, rule,modules={'And':all, 'Or':any})
>>> lam(*params)
False
```

This allows you to define your own functions that are used to do the mapping from symbolic to numerical.

Comment: My solution was probably wrong, the positive result I go was a win-shot of 1 in 4! (took me some tests to realize the results are off) due to the `.atoms` returning set. Anyway, you probably weren't doing unnecessary work.

Comment: @UrielEli I'm sorry to hear that:( Thanks for the feedback!